# POST Request Being Redirect to GET Request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, http-post, http-get

I am having a problem where POST requests are being redirected to GET requests.

I've tried solutions to several of the same questions on stackoverflow. But to this day I still have this problem not resolved.

What I have done:

- Clean route cache
- Change browser
- Changing the form view
- Change the route
- Change the redirect function on my controller

My Route

```
Route::post('confirmation', 'IklanController@confirmation')->name('confirmation');
```

My View

```
 <form action="{{ Route('pemilik.confirmation') }}" method="post">
     @csrf
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $member['kelas'] }}" name="kelas">
    <button class="btn btn-primary primary-custom" type="submit">Confirmation</button> 
 </form>
```

My Controller

```
 public function confirmation(Request $request)
 {
    ...

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

This is the result php artisan route:list

```
|  | POST | pemilik/confirmation | pemilik.confirmation | App\Http\Controllers\Pemilik\IklanController@confirmation
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the results of `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: you have named your route ``confirmation`` but you're calling a named route with ``pemilik.confirmation`` in the view.

Comment: You can't redirect to POST, so if there's a redirect involved it will always be a GET so don't redirect, post to the route directly

Comment: @shazyriver yes . I've added it

Comment: @OMiShah i using prefix in my route.

Comment: Kindly care to put the complete code then. How would we know 

Comment: And what do you mean by "Change the redirect function on my controller" as you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: also your  controller `IklanController` `confirmation` method code.

Comment: @shazyriver ``Route`` is a Facade while ``route`` is a helper method, so both should work. It doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: My bad, missed that.

Comment: @AndySong , finally the problem there is redirect on my controller

Comment: @OMiShah. sorry. I'm not careful

Answer (score -1):

the name of the route is `name('confirmation')` and the form action should be

```
`<form action="{{ route('confirmation') }}" method="post">
     @csrf
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $member['kelas'] }}" name="kelas">
    <button class="btn btn-primary primary-custom" type="submit">Confirmation</button> 
 </form>
```

`